# error in spring-security.xml:The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'http'

Tags: spring-security

I am developing application in spring for first time.Getting error at line no 11.Can any one solve this. I have added spring-security-config.jar.

```
  <?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.4.xsd">


        <http auto-config="true">
            <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="ROLE_USER" />

            <form-login 
                login-page="/login" 
                default-target-url="/welcome" 
                authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
                username-parameter="username"
                password-parameter="password" />
            <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout"  />
            <!-- enable csrf protection -->
            <csrf/>
        </http>

        <authentication-manager>
            <authentication-provider>
                <user-service>
                    <user name="mkyong" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
                </user-service>
            </authentication-provider>
        </authentication-manager>

    </beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set the `schemaLocation` for the security namespace. Copy the examples from [the reference manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-config) or one of the sample applications.

You've also tried to use version 2.0.4, which won't work. The `csrf` element is only available from 3.2 onwards.

I'd also forget about `auto-config` and add what you want explicitly.